# How do I get pandas / pylint running in Visual Studio Code on mac?

Tags: pandas, visual-studio

I've created a virtual env to run flask in a project in visual studio code. I have some code written in jupyter and when I copy this code to the .py file in vs studio, I get the following error message:

```
Unable to import 'pandas'pylint(import-error)
```

Could someone explain me please in plain english (for a beginner ) what I have to do to get it running?

Comment: Have you set the Python interpreter in VS Code?

Comment: I added this in the header and it worked: `#!/usr/bin/env python`